# extract data from text files to csv

Tags: text-processing

I have a series of text files with a consistent format like:

```
FirstName: Mary
LastName: Smith
Address: 123 Anywhere St
City: Nowhere
State: TX
Zip: 77777
```

I need to extract several lines from these files and output them into a csv file in a format like:

```
<filename>,<FirstName>,<City>,<Zip>
```

I can get the fields I want with a simple grep but I don't know how to get the output the way I need it.

Comment: What's your expected output

Comment: Sounds. like a simple Perl task. What is between Zip and the next First Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one record per file then this is a simple read loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

read_data()
{
  local first last addr city state zip

  file=$1

  while read -r header data
  do
    case $header in
      FirstName:) first=$data ;;
       LastName:) last=$data ;;
        Address:) addr=$data ;;
           City:) city=$data ;;
          State:) state=$data ;;
            Zip:) zip=$data ;;
               *) echo Ignoring bad line $header $data >&2
    esac
  done < $file
  echo "$file,$first,$last,$addr,$city,$state,$zip"
}

for file in *srcfiles*
do
  read_data $file
done
```

The `read_data` function reads each line and splits up the line into a "header" and a "data".  Once we get to the end of the file we just print out the results.

We call that function once for each source file via the `for` loop.

Note some potential gotcha's:  If there are commas in the data then this will break things, so you might want to do

```
  echo "\"$file\",\"$first\",\"$last\",\"$addr\",\"$city\",\"$state\",\"$zip\""
```

as the output to enclose everything inside `"..."` layout.  If there's any `"` in the data then this may cause the CSV to be malformed as well.

Adjust the `echo` line to match the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty approach, may suit your requirements.

```
grep . *|perl -ne 'if(/FirstName: (.*)/){$f=$1}if(/City: (.*)/){$c=$1}if(/^(.*):Zip: (.*)/){print "$1,$f,$c,$2\n"}'
```

Example:

```
grep . *
f1.txt:FirstName: Mary
f1.txt:LastName: Smith
f1.txt:Address: 123 Anywhere St
f1.txt:City: Nowhere
f1.txt:State: TX
f1.txt:Zip: 77777
f2.txt:FirstName: Joe
f2.txt:LastName: Bloggs
f2.txt:Address: 444 Anywhere St
f2.txt:City: Nowhere2
f2.txt:State: TXA
f2.txt:Zip: 77737
grep . *|perl -ne 'if(/FirstName: (.*)/){$f=$1}if(/City: (.*)/){$c=$1}if(/^(.*):Zip: (.*)/){print "$1,$f,$c,$2\n"}'
f1.txt,Mary,Nowhere,77777
f2.txt,Joe,Nowhere2,77737
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a single record per file and you have GNU awk, you could do

```
gawk -F': +' -vOFS=, '
  BEGINFILE{delete rec}
  {rec[$1] = $2}
  ENDFILE{print FILENAME, rec["FirstName"], rec["City"], rec["Zip"]}
' file1.txt file2.txt ...
```

Comment: Doesn't the `$2` mean that additional words will get lost? (eg "City: New York") would return "New".

Comment: @StephenHarris Doh! thanks - I have adjusted the field separator hopefully to fix that